# Organização de requisitos usando o backlog do Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, metodologia-ágil, requisitos

Recentemente comecei a usar o Visual Studio Team Services, principalmente pela disponibilidade de repositórios privados do Git gratuitamente.

Depois de um tempo percebi que ele tem vários recursos para gerenciar requisitos e o trabalho sendo realizado. Como eu trabalho sozinho, entre os modelos Scrum, Agile e CMMI eu escolhi o Agile.

Os recursos a que me refiro encontram-se na opção "Work" e lá podemos montar um backlog, visualizar uma board na qual podemos organizar o que há para fazer, o que está sendo feito, etc.

O backlog, pelo que eu sei, é onde os requisitos são organizados. Acontece que eu fico realmente perdido na hora de organizar os requisitos.

Em geral, ao entrar em contato com o usuário final do sistema para coletar os requisitos, o que acabamos conseguindo é uma lista com tudo que o usuário precisa. No momento até estou trabalhando em um projeto no qual o usuário me envia por e-mail uma lista dos requisitos do sistema.

Ao ter esse tipo de lista de requisitos eu preciso organizar lá, mas está sendo realmente complicado. Primeiro porque existem várias opções: features, epics, user stories (já até perguntei o significado disso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134585/quando-usar-user-stories-features-e-epics-no-visual-studio-team-services)), segundo porque existe como relacionar essas coisas, associar user stories a features e etc.

Como qualquer ferramenta, se esses recursos de backlog forem mal utilizados é claro que pode acabar gerando mais confusão do que organização.

É por isso que quero saber: como um desenvolvedor que trabalha sozinho pode utilizar esses recursos do Visual Studio Online para ter um backlog organizado? Como pegar uma lista informal de requisitos e organizar no backlog do Visual Studio Online de forma a deixar o trabalho organizado e facilitar o desenvolvimento?